# NullPointerException in my program Android

Tags: java, android

I getting error in my code when I press in button. Below gives my code in Java and error with logcat. How fix this bug? Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView example_text, result;
    EditText enter_data;
    Button send_data;

    private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        example_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_glowna_aktywnosc);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_wynik_dzialania);
        enter_data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etv_wprowadz_druga_liczbe);
        send_data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_przeslij_dane);

        send_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendDataAndWaitOnResult();


            }
        });
    }

    protected void SendDataAndWaitOnResult() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrugaActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("firstNumber", enter_data.getText().toString()); // <-- ERROR NUllPointerException
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

   // ....
}
```

EDIT:
Code logcat

```
04-17 18:27:59.512  30558-30558/kamiszczu.blogspot.com.przyklad_3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at kamiszczu.blogspot.com.przyklad_3.MainActivity.WyslijDaneICzekajNaWynik(MainActivity.java:46)
            at kamiszczu.blogspot.com.przyklad_3.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4209)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17431)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 18:27:59.628      521-540/? E/AppErrorDialog﹕ Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
04-17 18:28:59.559      521-563/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '423b4b28 kamiszczu.blogspot.com.przyklad_3/kamiszczu.blogspot.com.przyklad_3.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-17 18:29:46.020     521-4294/? E/DhcpStateMachine﹕ Error! Failed to handle a DHCP renewal on wlan0
04-17 18:29:48.674  31151-31624/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x627b70f8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x6235cab0 arg=0x0
04-17 18:29:48.675  31151-31624/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x627b70f8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
04-17 18:29:50.547      521-537/? E/FWKEXT﹕ Enter GetCurrentOP
```

In file Manifest.xml I have DrugaActivity. Error is in code Java.

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Have you declared DrugaActivity Class in your Manifest or not??

Comment: enter_data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etv_wprowadz_druga_liczbe); Is you declare their id in R.layout.activity_main ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I wrote the wrong name of the EditText during the cast. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Probably on of the objects in SendDataAndWaitOnResult method is null.

Try to check if enter_data or enter_data.getText() are null.

If enter_data is null you can't call getText(). 
The method toString() is not necessary because getText() also return String.

Comment: If i help u please aproove the anwser and close it.